# Find $f$ on $[1,a]$ such that $f \ge x\log x$, $f$ is strictly convex, analytic, and touches $x \log x$ only $n$ times.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

I am looking for a function $f$ defined on $[1,a]$ that satisfies the following:

1. $f(x) \ge x \log x$ on $[1,a]$
2. $f(x)$ is strictly convex
3. $f(x)$ is analytic  on $[1,a]$.
4. $f(x)-x\log(x)=0$ only **$n$** times on $[1,a]$.

My attempt was to construct $f$ as follows:

$f(x)=x\log(x)+g(x)$

where $g(x)$ would have oscillatory behavior (e.g., $\cos(x)$). However, every time I try to add oscillations I violate strict convexity condition.

Comment: Can you do $n=3$?  Say, $f(x) = x \log x$ only at the endpoints and one point between.

Comment: @GEdgar NO! Do you have an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example, $n=3$  on the interval $[1,3]$,

$$
f(x) = x\log x+\frac{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)^2}{10}
$$

It is analytic on $(0,+\infty)$.

Here is $f(x)$ on $[1,3]$
[image: f]

Here is $f(x) - x\log x$.  It is of course nonnegative and vanishes only at $1,2,3$.
[image: fxlx]

Here is $f''(x)$.  It is positive, so $f$ is strictly convex.
[image: fdd]
The coefficient $1/10$ was chosen so that $f''(x)$ is strictly positive.

If we consider $f(x)= x\log x+k(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)^2$ for $k>0$, then $f''(x)$
converges uniformly to $1/x$ as $k \to 0$, so of course we can choose $k$ so close to zero that $f''(x)$ is positive on $[1,3]$.

Comment: Thanks. Nice example.  Do you think there is a general procedure for doing this?

Comment: Of course.  You can do the same thing.  You can take an interval $[1,a]$ for any $a>1$.  You can choose any integer $n \ge 0$.  You can choose any $n$ points in $[1,a]$.  Then repeat what I did.  The commentary at the end about $k$ is what you need for this general case.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.....